# Perl Does IO::File work with Autodie?

Tags: perl, io

I'm trying to understand why `IO::File` doesn't seem to work with `use autodie`:

**Example #1**: Test program using `open`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use IO::File;

open( my $fh, "<", "bogus_file" );
# my $fh = IO::File->new( "bogus_file", "r" );
while ( my $line = $fh->getline )  {
    chomp $line;
    say qq(Line = "$line");
}
```

This fails with:

```
Can't open 'bogus_file' for reading: 'No such file or directory' at ./test.pl line 9
```

It looks like `autodie` is working.

**Example #2**: Same test program, but now using `IO::File`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;
use IO::File;

# open( my $fh, "<", "bogus_file" );
my $fh = IO::File->new( "bogus_file", "r" );
while ( my $line = $fh->getline )  {
    chomp $line;
    say qq(Line = "$line");
}
```

This fails with:

```
Can't call method "getline" on an undefined value at ./test.pl line 11.
```

Looks like `autodie` didn't catch the bad `IO::File->new` open.

Yet, as far as I can tell, `IO::File->new` uses `open` underneath. Here's the code from `IO::File`:

```
sub new {
    my $type = shift;
    my $class = ref($type) || $type || "IO::File";
    @_ >= 0 && @_ <= 3
        or croak "usage: $class->new([FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]]])";
    my $fh = $class->SUPER::new();
    if (@_) {
        $fh->open(@_)   # <-- Calls "open" method to open file.
            or return undef;
    }
    $fh;
}

sub open {
    @_ >= 2 && @_ <= 4 or croak 'usage: $fh->open(FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]])';
    my ($fh, $file) = @_;
    if (@_ > 2) {
        my ($mode, $perms) = @_[2, 3];
        if ($mode =~ /^\d+$/) {
            defined $perms or $perms = 0666;
            return sysopen($fh, $file, $mode, $perms);
        } elsif ($mode =~ /:/) {
            return open($fh, $mode, $file) if @_ == 3;
            croak 'usage: $fh->open(FILENAME, IOLAYERS)';
        } else {
            #  <--- Just a standard "open" statement...
            return open($fh, IO::Handle::_open_mode_string($mode), $file);
        }
    }
    open($fh, $file);
}
```

What's causing `autodie` not to work as expected?

Comment: My understanding is that `autodie` is lexically scoped.  Therefore it changes calls to `open` in your file, but not within IO::File.

Comment: I wish the Perldoc was a bit more specific -- either the `IO::File` or the `autodie` Perldoc. Autodie says its lexically scoped, but then precedes to show how to use it in blocks. Warnings is also lexically scoped, but I guess I hadn't noticed it before. Thanks for your answer. It sort of makes the use of `autodie` a bit less useful.

Comment: @David W., What? No. autodie would be totally useless if it was an all or nothing for your entire interpreter.

Comment: @tjd care to put that up as an answer? Anyway, the relationship between file handles, core functions and `IO::*` objects is weird. All file handles are objects in newer perls, but the methods are wrappers for the core functions. They are not aliases, so when `CORE::open` is called, it gets called from `IO::File`. It would be dangerous for `autodie` to globally change the semantics of any core function. A false-ish return value of `open` is perfectly desirable with more advanced modes, e.g. when using `open` to `fork`.

Comment: @ikegami Autodie helps turn Perl into an exception based language. If I don't check for errors with certain commands, Autodie will catch those  errors. If I don't want my program to die, I have to _handle_ the exception. However, Autodie is inconsistent. `unlink` and `link` will Autodie, but not `copy` and `move`. Autodie will catch `rmdir` and `mkdir`errors, but not necessarily `make_path` and `remove_tree`. Not with `IO`, but with `open`, `close, `print``. If I use Autodie, I have to know which commands work with autodie which means I can't depend upon it.

Comment: @David W., Why are you telling me any of that? I know what autodie does,  which you be obvious from the fact that I answered your question

Comment: @amon, it's been that way at least since 5.6

Comment: @David W., Why are you telling me any of that? Was that meant for someone else?

Comment: You said _autodie would be totally useless if it was all or nothing_. Really, it's the other way around. Autodie strives to make Perl _exception based_. If I forget to _handle_ a failed command, my program should die. However, Autodie ends up being inconsistent.  Some _commands_ will fail on Autodie, but I have to remember which ones. I might as well opt for consistency and get into the habit of checking the status of my commands.

Comment: @David W, If autodie affected the entire interpreter, it would break just about every module and script in existence. Noone could ever use autodie. A module noone can use is totally useless. Nothing you said addresses any of that.

Comment: Re "Some commands will fail on Autodie, but I have to remember which ones." Well, for starters, it only affects certain named *operators*, but no method calls (e.g. `IO::File->new`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`autodie` is lexically scoped. Therefore it changes (wraps) calls to `open` in your file, but not within `IO::File`.